# 'NAMESPACE' command with a 'BAD' response: User is authenticated but not connected

Tags: c#, mailkit

I am trying to connect into Outlook mailbox, fetching, extracting data from mails. My problem is, that after few seconds will show this exception.

> MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapCommandException: The IMAP server replied to the 'NAMESPACE' command with a 'BAD' response: User is authenticated but not connected.

My token and username is correct so I am kinda stumped

```cs
    using (var client = new ImapClient(new ProtocolLogger("imapLog.txt")))
    {
        try
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync("outlook.office.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
            await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (client.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Authentication Successful");

                var inbox = client.Inbox;    
                inbox.Open(MailKit.FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

                Console.WriteLine("Total messages: {0}", inbox.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Recent messages: {0}", inbox.Recent);

                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed");
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
        }             
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that you used the correct username/password, but you haven't gone into your account settings and enabled IMAP access.